# how to import pillow into cpanel django project

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library, cpanel

I want to make an update to my website which is made with django, I want to add an online store section that is managed from the django administrator, but when I want to do the makemigrations, it tells me that I cannot use imageFields, since it does not I have Pillow installed in the project, but it doesn't let me install pillow, I tried other versions, in many ways in the requirements.txt, but there is no way to let me add pillow to the django app.
One very important thing is that I do not have the terminal in cpanel, I cannot have it, they only let me add the scripts and pip install in the way you will see in the following image:
[Here you can see what the format is like to add scripts or pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc5Du.png)

and when I want to install using pip install the requirements.txt tells me this:

> Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-32phlj94/Pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package Pillow produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=Pillow fragments.  Failed building wheel for unknown  Failed building wheel for unknownCommand "/home2/cannareiscom/virtualenv/CANNAb/3.9/bin/python3.9_bin -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-32phlj94/Pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-i_xg6rjm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home2/cannareiscom/virtualenv/CANNAb/3.9/include/site/python3.9/unknown" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-32phlj94/Pillow/You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 23.3.1 is available.You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I get that error when I run the requirements.txt with the pip install, inside the requirements.txt there is only Pillow==10.1.0, also try with the lowercase P, also try with other versions, like 7.2.0, and more... there is no way it will let me install pillow, if you could help me it would be great.

Answer (score -2):

Try this `pip install Pillow==8.3.2`

Comment: Why would you expect this particular version to work? How did you know that?  Please [edit] your answer to provide extra details.